# Make links side by side in nav menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to customize the [Dashboard Template example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/).

How can I add a link right next to the other, using Bootstrap?

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></li>
<li><a href="#">Reports</a><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></a></li>
</ul>
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/blg694f.png]

Answer (score 0):

Use span and include li and icons

```
  <li><span><a href="#">Reports</a><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></a></span></li>
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/dXWgwA

You can use two different links for li - Reports and icon .

Comment: @Lucas Pottersky , if you want to remove link for li -Reports, you just need to remove the a tag for Reports and keep link for icon

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `display` rule to `inline` and adjust the `padding` for those two anchors. You may also want to adapt the hover styles.

```css
.nav > li.xtr-padding {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.nav > li > a.inline-anchor {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 15px 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav > li > a.inline-anchor:first-child {
  padding: 0 4px 0 15px;
}

.nav > li:hover .inline-anchor, .nav > li:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: rgb(35, 82, 124);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a></li>
  <li class="xtr-padding"><a href="#" class="inline-anchor">Reports</a><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus inline-anchor"></a></li>
</ul>
```